# iOS10 UILabel use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping has half character ，how to fix it？

Tags: ios

[image]

this is UILabel show half character！！！

[image: show]

this is UILabel attribute！！！

[image: attribute]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linebreaking is only working if the label have the chance to break the line. But with "Lines" set to 1, there is no chance.

Set the Lines to 0 (auto) or at least to 2 and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

just set auto shrink to minimum font scale from storyboard so it will automatically set the size of font according to the label width or programmatically set [self.yourlablename sizToFit]

Comment: He want to line break and not to auto shrink, so this is not a good fix.